# How do I start using Hadoop? Do I need a bunch of computers?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, distributed-computing

I have a program that would take a very long time (biology and protein related) if I ran it on one machine. But if I split it up into chunks I could run them all and combine the results.

Can Hadoop do this? Do I need a bunch of computers to run such a thing? How should I get started?

Comment: Definitely NOT by asking this question

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: http://strata.oreilly.com/2011/01/what-is-hadoop.html

Answer (score 1):

your question is quite general. Yes, hadoop is one of the available frameworks to do distributed computing. It is however impossible to know if it is the right approach for your problem.

The first thing you have to think about is whether or not your problem can be solved by distributing your computation. If you can split your calculation and your data between different nodes, then that should work. (look at the Map/reduce approach)

To start with, try http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/ , Burhan's link or other google...

Then, you can choose a distro (I like cloudera), it's much easier to install.

And yes, obviously you would need several machines, that's the point.